# Using horizontal line to fit the model

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am writing a python code using horizontal line for investigating the under-fiting using the function sin(2.pi.x) in range of [0,1]. 
I first generate N data points by adding some random noise using Gaussian distribution with mu=0 and sigma=1.

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np

   # generate N random points
   N=30
   X= np.random.rand(N,1)
   y= np.sin(np.pi*2*X)+ np.random.randn(N,1)
```

I need to fit the model using horizontal line and display it. But I don't know how to do next.
Could you help me figure out this problem? I'd appreciate about it.

Comment: A horizontal line is simply positionned at the mean of the data. `plt.plot(X, np.ones_like(X)*y.mean())`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you're generating a noisy Sine wave and trying to fit a horizontal line?

```
import os
import fnmatch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate N random points
N=60
X= np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi, num=N)
noise = 0.1 * np.random.randn(N)
y= np.sin(4*X) + noise

numer = sum([xi*yi for xi,yi in zip(X, y)]) - N * np.mean(X) * np.mean(y)
denum = sum([xi**2 for xi in X]) - N * np.mean(X)**2
b = numer / denum
A = np.mean(y) - b * np.mean(X)

y_ = b * X+ A

plt.plot(X,y)
plt.plot(X,y_)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why the manual `for` loops (e.g. `numer = sum([xi*yi for xi,yi in zip(X, y)])`) if you can do something as simple as `numer = np.sum(X*y)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use the least squares loss function, by definition you are trying to find the value of `yhat` minimizing `np.sum((y-yhat)**2)`. Differentiating by `yhat`, you'll find that the minimum is achieved at `yhat = np.sum(y)/N`, which is of course nothing but `y.mean()`, as also already pointed out by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the comments.

```
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, np.zeros(N) + np.mean(y))
```

[image: Plot of mean]

Comment: Stackoverflow includes plethora of different questions which already answer this. Also, the line is not horizontal.

Comment: Ah, completely missed the part about them wanting a constant fit; let me update.